# Vnet not listing while creating a Azure Api Management

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-api-management, vnet

I have created a Vnet and subnet for a Azure Api management service but when I try to provision the ApiM and trying to select the internal Vnet that's created it doesn't seem to be listing in the drop down

Answer (score 1):

You have to deploy API Management in the same region as your VNET:

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2

> A virtual network and subnet in the **same region** and subscription as your API Management instance. A dedicated subnet is recommended but not required.

Comment: I've checked that too...I've kept both vnet and subnet under same region both..yet it's not listing....for some reason only this one vnet is not listing while other vnets of the subscription seem to list